# Oracle SQL rules design

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm starting with an idea for my work, where I can set a couple of rules to validate where tables have the owner in front and other couple of rules. 
I thought using BNF notation but I don't really have an idea how to start or even if it's another better idea for what I want.
I'm actually working as DevOps but recently had to work with my Dev group and this issue came out.

I don't know much about Oracle code so I'm looking for some guidance for where can I start researching and accomplish this or a good sustainable idea to bring to the Dev team

For example: I have 30 different scripts that they have: check tables, create tables, add columns, insert data, and so on. And I don't want to check one by one reading 4000+ lines of code, because of course it's tedious. I want to make a script to help me with that, checking line one by one and fixing the "problems".

Before:

```
INSERT INTO table
(column1, column2, ... )
VALUES
(expression1, expression2, ... );
```

After:

```
INSERT INTO owner.table
(column1, column2, ... )
VALUES
(expression1, expression2, ... );
```

Comment: I dont see any question here.  This isnt on-topic for this [**forum**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: The question here, is what can I use to create a rule set script to check like create table scripts (4000 lines of code scripts or even bigger ones) have all certain things that they have to be set, example: owner.table

Comment: Didn't knew about the topics if it's the case. Will post where it has to be

Comment: well at first I tought was you looking for a `recomendation` and that is offtopic. But now looks like you need to provide more information about what you need. Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Just edited into the question

Comment: You are probably asking the wrong question [**What is the XY problem?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) how we will know what mean `checking line one by one and fixing the "problems".`

Comment: Sometimes my team just fall in exceptions cause they didn't set tables properly, or didn't just set the owner. Briefly I want to make a script to define rules and make some automated sql code revision with self set rules. Something that go throw all the script code take the rules and fix owner missing at packages, owners missing at tables, inserts deletes and create with commit in front of it, check to not have slash at the E D of the script... Just want my team don't have more work to do.

Comment: that looks like a job for an app parsing the script files, not for sql.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [SonarQube](https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#languages=plsql)?

Comment: That's pretty much what I thought. Gonna have to find another way to get this solved. Thanks anyway for persist with this.  Really appreciate

Comment: I will make some research and give feedback tomorrow

Comment: Why do you want to hardcode the owner name in the insert statement? You're better off using synonyms to ensure your code refers to the correct table.

Comment: Client rules, not my decision in this case

Comment: @JonHeller It was pretty much what i was looking for, now i was testing the PL/SQL parser that i have seen it's commercial only with a free short license. Do you know any other opensource software for this job like [SonarQube](https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#languages=plsql)? That can handle custom rules?

Comment: @FrancoPapalardo The closest I know of is the [ANTLR Grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/plsql/plsql.g4).  Although that's only a parser, you'd have to build a rule system.  And I have doubts about that parser, or any PL/SQL parser, working with a high degree of accuracy.  Oracle has 2175 keywords, most of which are only partially reserved, and many weird syntax rules.  It's one of the most difficult programming languages to parse.

Comment: @JonHeller there is a way to parse it too using SQL Grammar, I think it's referenced to ANTLR, it's the bnf notation. There was a program for windows but it's out of date, using sql 89 grammar, it's called [Gold Parser Builder](http://www.goldparser.org/builder/index.htm), I was not able to find any .grm file for sql 2003 or above to just try that old programm, I prefer SonarQube so far but can't really implement a commercial software at least for now in my work. I will keep doing some research and post anything I find in the future here just to help others

Comment: @FrancoPapalardo Unfortunately, for PL/SQL, you may not even be able to trust commercial parsers.  I've tried some in the past but had problems with even moderately complex code.  In my experience, if a problem calls for parsing Oracle SQL, it's best to avoid the problem.  But it depends on how accurate you need it to be.  If 95% is good enough, then there are solutions.  If you need something 99.9% accurate, you will be sorely disappointed and may only realize it after it's too late.

Comment: @JonHeller I don't need any code review it's more like specific custom rules that client want, even the rules they want are extras, like this owner. rule or others like no / at the end of the script and many other rules that they want. Not really seeing the point with this, and because it's a plus to check my sql code i was using a parser, but don't really care much about the code itself